# How can i merge many css classes atributes into a single class

Tags: css

I'm having the same attribute for different 4 classess. So i want to reduce the code weight. So how can i make it as a single common class.

```
    .iass-general-config-wrapper h2
           {
               padding-bottom: 1px!important;
            }
    .iass-workload-config-wrapper h2
           {
               padding-bottom: 1px!important;
            }
     .iass-network-config-wrapper h2
            {
                padding-bottom: 1px!important;
              }
      .vdi-review-wrapper
            {
                 padding-bottom: 1px!important;
             }
```

Comment: use the same class name instead of different class names at the different places for same values

Comment: @user3470953 That is not smart, classes are there for so you can give simulair looking the same style, but meaby need .class1 a red border and class2 a green one.. if you like.. http://jsfiddle.net/Andelhofs/k81qqjws/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at, this will bring you far far away

> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```
h4, h5, h6 {
   color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can "merge" them together as a multiple selector rule

```
.iass-general-config-wrapper h2,
.iass-workload-config-wrapper h2,
.iass-network-config-wrapper h2,
.vdi-review-wrapper
{
    padding-bottom: 1px!important;
}
```

Or as noted in the comments you could simply create a new class and apply that, resulting in much less code

```
.padding-bottom
{
     padding-bottom: 1px !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks. i think it should work. i've seen like this in some of our codes. thanks you :-)

Comment: @srini No problem at all